# Leaves Not Rendering Properly

Tags: sapling-addon

I'm not very experienced with Blender, and am returning to it after quite a long break as well. So I'm not very familiar with Blender.

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlRF5S0aHwU) tutorial (@ 20min), and am running into an issue when trying to render my leaves. I was able to render the bark no problem, but when I attempt to render the leaves, I only see a weird outline of the leaf. Let me know what other pieces of information you'll need.

[image: Workflow]

Comment: Try switching the Transparent and the rest of shaders in the Mix shader.

Comment: That kind of worked. But now they're translucent with a white hue to them. https://i.imgur.com/kpl4GsH.jpg

Comment: Don't mix transparent shader with color information from texture as factor, use alpha information from that texture (if it's present). If it doesn't work then I think your problem depends on your node setup / image used thus is more localized and requires your blend uploaded, to share it use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.